# Polygonize tool not giving output in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I am very new to QGIS (long time ESRI user that is making the transition).

I am using QGIS 3.0.3 and I am trying to make polygons from a raster layer by value.  Unfortunately every time that I attempt to do this I get the following error in the log.  I am certain (given my time learning new programs) that this is a silly human error but I also know that those can eat up an entire day.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it's worth trying to output to a file that doesn't have any spaces in the name.

Comment: I can't tell you how frustrating it is when it is that simple.  I really appreciate your input!

Comment: Did that fix the problem?

Comment: It absolutely did, now on to the next problem :D  Is there a way that I can give credit to you fixing the problem via a vote up on your comment?  I am new here and still learning.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer so it's easier for others with the same question to find.

Comment: Click the green check mark next to the answer. That marks the answer as "accepted" and other site users will know that it actually solved the problem.

Comment: Are you certain the error is due to the space in the path? The GDAL command output above reports "Failed to create directory J:\Power Analysis\BcPoly.shp". Maybe there's a permission error with the "J:\Power Analysis" path which caused the fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes having a space in the file name is a problem in QGIS. The solution is choosing an output file destination without any spaces in the filepath.